# Create a custom action for rules in Outlook

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook

I would like to create a custom action for rules in outlook 2007 or 2010.

Can I have an example of any type of code that create any custom action so from that I can 
have an idea of how to create my custom action (that does its specific action)?

Comment: Hey! I know it was a long time ago, but I'm wondering... did you find a way to do it? I'd like to have something similar for my project.